# Getting Primary Key from Tastypie Resource URI

Tags: django, api, tastypie

I have a Django - tastypie Resource as follows. It has multiple fields that has Many to Many Relations.

I am trying to get the fields "workflow_initiators", "workflow_submitters" and "workflow_approvers" and add the user to a respective group namely initiators, submitters and approvers.

**My JSON Request as follows :**

```
{

"workflow_approvers": [
"/client/api/v1/user/44/",
"/client/api/v1/user/6/"
],
"workflow_dept": [
"/client/api/v1/departments/1/",
"/client/api/v1/departments/2/"
],
"workflow_initators": [
"/client/api/v1/user/44/",
"/client/api/v1/user/6/"
],
"workflow_name": "Hello Workflow",
"workflow_submitters": [
"/client/api/v1/user/43/",
"/client/api/v1/user/6/"
],

}
```

I want to get the primary key from resource uri of tastypie in a **hydrate()** or a **obj_create()** method. In order to get the pk i used a function **get_pk_from_uri()**. But it throws an error of the following

```
error : global name 'get_pk_from_uri' is not defined
```

**My Resource as follows :**

```
class WorkflowResource(ModelResource):

    workflow_dept = fields.ToManyField(DepartmentsResource, 'workflow_dept', related_name='departments', full=True)
    workflow_initators = fields.ToManyField(UserResource, 'workflow_initators', related_name='user')
    workflow_submitters = fields.ToManyField(UserResource, 'workflow_submitters', related_name='user')
    workflow_approvers = fields.ToManyField(UserResource, 'workflow_approvers', related_name='user')

    def obj_create(self, bundle, **kwargs):
        submitters = bundle.data.get('workflow_submitters', [])
        for submitter in submitters:
            print(get_pk_from_uri(submitter)) # Throws Error

            #Adding User to Group Logic
            # g = Group.objects.get(name='submitters') 
            # g.user_set.add(your_user)

    class Meta:
        queryset = WorkflowIndex.objects.filter(is_active=True)
        resource_name = 'workflows'
        list_allowed_methods = ['get', 'post']
        detail_allowed_methods = ['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete', 'patch']
        serializer = Serializer()
        default_format = 'application/json'
        authentication = Authentication()
        authorization = DjangoAuthorization()
        always_return_data = True
```

Is there any other method to get the primary key and other fields from resource uri ? I did see get_via_uri() method but was unsure on how to implement the same.

Kindly guide me in resolving this issue.

**References :**

1. [Stackoverflow - Get model object from tastypie uri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16331120/get-model-object-from-tastypie-uri)
2. [Tastypie Documents - get_via_uri()](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/v0.9.9/resources.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should go back to this post: [Get model object from tastypie uri?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16331120/get-model-object-from-tastypie-uri)

The `get_pk_from_uri(uri)` method that you can see in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18832407/2255491) is not part of the source code of Tastypie, as you can check [here](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=get_pk_from_uri&type=Code).

I suppose the guy wrote it by himself, and you should do the same sothat you won't get the `error : global name 'get_pk_from_uri' is not defined` error. I didn't tested his method thought.

Comment: David, is there anyother method that i can use to get the primary key for resource uri ?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**
David was correct. The get_pk_from_uri() is not an in built tasty-pie method, which i was mistaken.

P.S : I'm just making the answer clear so that someone find it useful.

When needed to extract the resource name or pk from the resource uri of tastypie. we will be able to access them from **kwargs of the below section. The Kwargs contains the follows

```
kwargs
{u'api_name': 'v1', u'pk': '1', u'resource_name': 'workflows'}
```

Add the following code to your resources.py or utils.py and include it in your API's to a get this method get_pk_from_uri

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import resolve, get_script_prefix


def get_pk_from_uri(uri):
    prefix = get_script_prefix()
    chomped_uri = uri

    if prefix and chomped_uri.startswith(prefix):
       chomped_uri = chomped_uri[len(prefix) - 1:]

    try:
        view, args, kwargs = resolve(chomped_uri)
    except Resolver404:
        raise NotFound("The URL provided '%s' was not a link to a valid resource." % uri)

    return kwargs['pk']
```